# Form input memory for radioboxes, checkboxes & dropdown(selection) form

Tags: php

im fairly new to php and I've been having trouble having the form save the memory for radioboxes, checkboxes & (dropdown) selection list in form so whatever data I put or select will still be there when I submit it.

```html
  <select  name = "province[]" multiple size = "12">
    
 <?php foreach ($PROVINCES as $key => $value) {?>
   <option value = "<?php echo $value ?>"<?php (in_array('$key',$_POST['province'] ) )?'selected':'';?>><?php echo $value ?></option>    
<?php }?>
    </select> 
   <br><br>
 <label for = "status">Status(Mult Select)<font color = "red">*</font></label>
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "status[]" id = "Approved" value= "Approved"> Approved 
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "status[]" id = "Pending Application" value="Pending Application"> Pending Application 
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "status[]" id = "Active Service" value="Active Service"> Active Service 
   <br><br>
 <label for = "location">Location<font color = "red">*</font></label>
 <input type = "radio" name = "location" id = "Garage" value = "Garage"> Garage
 <input type = "radio" name = "location" id= "Attic" value = "Attic"> Attic
 <input type = "radio" name = "location" id = "House" value = "House"> House
   </fieldset>
```

Comment: see checkbox's attribute [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/checkbox). It will work for the radio buttons too.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use PHP [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to echo out the checked status.
Also, always good to view the status of your POST parameters (helpful figuring out what browser sends to server)

```html
<pre><?php var_dump($_POST); ?></pre>
<input <?php if(in_array('Approved', $_POST['status'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> type = "checkbox" name = "status[]" id = "Approved" value= "Approved"> Approved 
<input <?php if(in_array('Pending Application', $_POST['status'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> type = "checkbox" name = "status[]" id = "Pending Application" value="Pending Application"> Pending Application
```

Hope that will get you on track. Note: there are much better methods available to manage Form elements via PHP though. Look for any frameworks, e.g. Zend Framework.

Comment: for some odd reason it's changing the box into textbox

Comment: Well .. thats what the "Run code snippet" does. In fact, when you take this script and run it on the server side, it runs fine. Save the code in some PHP file and run it; should be just fine.